# Specifying the field naming policy for Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have question related to bean to json serialziation/deserialization using Jackson. Previously I have used GSON to do that, but now I am faced with a project that already depends on Jackson and I would prefer not to introduce new dependency if I can do with what I already have at hand.

So imagine I have a bean like:

```
class ExampleBean {
   private String firstField;
   private String secondField;
   // respective getters and setters
}
```

And then Jackson serializes it to:

```
{
   "firstField": "<first_field_value>",
   "secondField": "<second_field_value>"
}
```

I am using the following code to produce the above result:

```
ExampleBean bean;
...
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(outStream, bean);
```

However I would like (am expected) to get the following serialization:

```
{
   "first_field": "<first_field_value>",
   "second_field": "<second_field_value>"
}
```

I have deliberately simplified my example, but I have big hierarchy of beans that I want to serialize and I want to specify that the serialized attributes should always be in snake_style (that is with underscores) and the corresponding bean fields should always be camelCased. Is there any way I can enforce such field /attribute naming policies and use them without annotating the corresponding attribute for every field?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

And yes I found it (it turned out that after 2 hours of searching I had been only 30 minutes away from finding it):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
mapper.writeValue(outStream, bean);
```

Hopefully this will turn out to be helpful to somebody else too.

Comment: ObjectMapper doesnt seem to have such a method setPropertyNamingStrategy... :(

Comment: @stantonk used to be when i wrote my comment. Apparently it was in there for Jackson 1.9. However, I do not find equivalent in the most recent Jackson library. Please, if you do, write back here an answer so that people would be able to refer to it.

Comment: figured it out, i had an older version of jackson being included via a transitive dependency, and my IDE imported the wrong one :-).

Comment: you can get it working with<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: For anyone using latest Jackson, use `PropertyNamingStrategies` instead of `PropertyNamingStrategy`. I spent far to long trying to figure out why `PropertyNamingStrategy` was deprecated and what to replace it with.

Answer (score 4):

Now `CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` is the deprecated strategy use `SNAKE_CASE` instead

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
mapper.writeValue(outStream, bean);
```